# iMovie tutorial or video?

Tags: imovie

Can you recommend a good site with some online training for the latest iMovie on OS X? I have tried to play with iMovie over the years and I never seem to 'get' how it is meant to be used.

Right now I have about 1.5 hours of raw video taken with my iPhone 5s of a set of student presentation and I (naively) wanted to make a short 'highlight real' of it. But once I import the video into iMovie I am not sure how to use its features.

(Note that I am very proficient on my mac in every other respect, software development, html, photoshop, illustrator, all those I manage just fine, but iMovie is so confusing. I feel like I just need a 20 minute leg up in a tutorial or something like that.)

### Update:

Here's a screenshot of what I am using: I have played with it a while and I don't see any commands which would make it look like the screenshot in the help screenshot provided below... *what am i missing?????*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a video tutorial, this screencast on YouTube is pretty helpful:

- [NEW iMovie 2013: The Basics and Overview (In-Depth Tutorial)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjF2y5NABq0&t=3m3s)

Apple provides a very detailed guide on iMovie, available from Help → iMovie Help or online.

- http://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.0

[image: Help Center → iMovie Help]

Comment: Yes I saw that but I am still not clear on some basic concepts... Events, Projects, Clips, what does all that really mean? Also the screen I see when I run it is totally different from what I see in the help (e.g. the screenshot above even...)

Comment: @pitosalas Which version of iMovie do you have? What are you referring to 'seeing differently'? The timeline won't be the same because you won't have added any clips.

Comment: well the about box says 10.0.1 which I think is the latest, although everyone talks about iMovie '11 which I thought stood for 2011, which is really an old copy. But I am pretty certain it's the most recent one... Is it?

Comment: @pitosalas Yes 10.0.1 is the latest. Do you get anything that resembles that screenshot or something *completely* different?

Comment: see in original post, I added a screenshot. It's similar but I can't see where and how all those panes come from. I am sounding really dumb, but I am missing just a few nuggets of info to get going, hence, looking a screencast/tutorial or what not :)..... And by the way, why do the call it iMovie '11?

Comment: @pitosalas You have to import some footage first for it to show something! Click the Import button on the toolbar and select your footage :) iMovie '11 is iMovie 9. I've added a link to a tutorial on YouTube.